# how to align column from csv file using awk tool

Tags: linux, awk, sed

```
#!/bin/bash
#for odering the table
awk -F "," ' {print $1" " $2" " $3}' /home/rishabh/Desktop/mi1.csv
```

I have written the above script to print formated output from a csv file 
but i want to align age properly in a single column. I have tried using `column-t` but its not producing satisfactory result can anyone please look into output snapshot and help me to get aligned results please.

[image: image for output]

Comment: Use `printf()` to specify column widths.

Comment: Please add sample input (text, no image) and your desired output (text, no image) for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Post a [mcve] that includes concise, testable sample input and expected output **as text**. Posting an image of some undesirable output is about as useful as asking a mechanic to fix your car by only showing him a photo of a puddle of oil under your car instead of bringing her the actual car.

Answer (score 3):

if that's all in your file and just to display them in tabular form

```
$ column -ts, file
```

will do it for you.